# Postgres value update in ARRAY form

Tags: arrays, postgresql, procedure, sql-update

my motive is to update multiple values in table through an array.
Below is the sample procedure created for the same

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE blkupd(_newitem TEXT ARRAY, _id INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
 UPDATE users                         
 SET user_name = _newitem[1], user_password = _newitem[2]
 WHERE user_id = _id
$$
```

And I'm calling the procedure like this

```
CALL blkupd('{bc, df}', 4);
```

MY QUESTION IS "what if array is passed only 1 value?",
if only 1 value is passed and i want that value to be updated in the password column.

Suppose i give entry "ab" to array
by following the below code

```
 SET user_name = _newitem[1], user_password = _newitem[2]
```

wouldn't the "ab" goes to user_name.
but i want it in the user_password column, KEEPING the user_name unchanged.
HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THAT?

Comment: Pass two named parameters instead of an array. Much safer and much easier to understand and use

Comment: well the motive is to use array. I want to use it on large scale.

Comment: You simply can't use an array for what you are trying to achieve here. If you really want to make the API fragile, then you could pass key/value pairs through a JSON value.